# Installing JPA pluggin for Eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink, eclipse-juno

I'm new to eclipse, I want to install JPA plugging so I can benefit of the JPA wizard and import entity classes easily ... I tried to download it using eclipse install software menu using eclipse juno repository, I found many links, I tried to download them all, but during the downloading, I get an error saying 'installing software' has encountered a problem, An error occurred while collecting items to be installed :

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,commonj.sdo,2.1.1.v201112051852
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.activation,1.1.0.v201108011116
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.mail,1.4.0.v201005080615
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.persistence,2.0.4.v201112161009
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.persistence,2.0.5.v201212031355
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.servlet,2.4.0.v200806031604
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.ws.rs,1.1.1.v20101004-1200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.wsdl,1.6.2.v201012040545
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.xml.bind,2.2.0.v201105210648
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.xml.stream,1.0.1.v201004272200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.collections,3.2.0.v201005080500
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.lang,2.1.0.v201005080500
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.velocity,1.5.0.v200905192330
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem,2.0.600.v201201051400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.workbench,2.0.400.v201104251400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.branding,1.2.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.core,1.2.2.v201301082148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.eclipselink.branding,1.2.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.eclipselink.core,1.2.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jpt.common.eclipselink.feature,1.2.1.v201208222210-3318s73573J777753
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jpt.common.feature,1.2.2.v201301082148-664AkF7BG7WDLFEEF
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.ui,1.2.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.utility,2.1.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.dbws.eclipselink.branding,1.1.101.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.dbws.eclipselink.core.gen,1.0.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jpt.dbws.eclipselink.feature,1.1.102.v201301101606-797EBpCcNBHLEeHXGVaV4KKI
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.dbws.eclipselink.ui,1.0.201.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.doc.user,1.4.2.v201205290002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.branding,1.2.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core,1.2.2.v201301082148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.core.schemagen,1.0.201.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.branding,1.2.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.core,1.2.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.core.schemagen,1.1.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.feature,1.3.2.v201301092252-777B5BgJ9EJAgHNGrMm1f9e
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.ui,1.3.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.feature,1.2.2.v201301082148-56ACAkF7BG7WDLFEEF
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.ui,1.3.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.branding,3.2.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core,3.2.2.v201301092252
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db,2.1.101.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.ui,2.0.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.branding,3.2.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core,2.2.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen,2.1.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.feature,3.2.2.v201301082148-7K7J78EVVFNVHz0NgOXgX4KKI
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.ui,2.2.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.feature,3.2.2.v201301091616-7U7K8qFC7sRdwVKaof36y4KKI
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen,2.2.2.v201301082148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui,3.2.2.v201301092252
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.annotations.controller,1.1.300.v200908252030
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.annotations.core,1.1.300.v201004141630
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.frameworks,1.1.601.v201208160700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.201.v201108161900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.ui,1.4.200.v201008182133
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.ui,1.0.201.v201208292200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee,1.1.603.v201301092200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core,1.2.200.v201205030130
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb,1.1.601.v201210040812
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.annotation.model,1.1.300.v201003112036
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.jca,1.1.600.v201111012200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ui,1.1.600.v201205170400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web,1.1.601.v201212130700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jee,1.0.501.v201301091334
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.core,1.2.302.v20120503_1042
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.antlr,3.2.0.v201206041011
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.antlr.source,3.2.0.v201206041011
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.asm,3.3.1.v201206041142
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.asm.source,3.3.1.v201206041142
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.core,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.core,2.4.2.v20121206-a9d0e8d
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.core.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.dbws,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.dbws,2.4.2.v20121206-a9d0e8d
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.builder,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.builder,2.4.2.v20121206-a9d0e8d
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.builder.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.dbws,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.dbwsbuilder,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.dbwsbuilder.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa,2.4.2.v20121206-a9d0e8d
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.equinox,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.equinox.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.equinox.weaving,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.equinox.weaving.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql,2.0.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql,2.0.1.v20121206-a9d0e8d
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.source,2.0.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.source,2.0.1.v20121206-a9d0e8d
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.osgi,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.osgi.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.moxy,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.moxy,2.4.2.v20121206-a9d0e8d
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.moxy,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.nosql,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.nosql,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.oracle,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.oracleddlparser,1.0.0.v20120628
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.oracleddlparser.source,1.0.0.v20120628
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.sdk,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.sdo,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.sdo,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.sdo.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.persistence.sdo.source,2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui,1.4.300.v201111030424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.core,1.1.602.v201210091733
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.ui,1.0.702.v201211262010
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.core,1.1.602.v201301032305
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.ui,1.0.702.v201211262010
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.internet.monitor.core,1.0.505.v20110419
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core,1.1.202.v201208171701
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.manipulation,1.0.400.v201204261600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui,1.1.202.v201208171701
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery,1.0.300.v20120403_0949
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.ui,1.4.100.v20121112_1718
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.web,1.1.600.v201204190200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.web.ui,1.1.600.v201109220400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jdom,1.0.0.v201005080400
```

What I should I do to get this fixed, I should precise that I downloaded an offline version but I couldn't know how to integrate it, please clarify things to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download OEPE...the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse. They actually have a full download containing Eclipse. Just google Oracle OEPE and you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem typically means some problem occurred with downloading the jars from the update site.  Note that this also means that you got passed the first stage of determining which jars to install (which requires a network connection to determine what should be installed).

This means one of several things:

1. Your firewall is blocking the download of the jars.  Go to Preferences -> General -< Network Connections to fix this
2. You lost connectivity partway through the install process3.
3. Your local cache of update site contents is old or corrupted.  Go to Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available software sites.  Select all sites and click "Reload" and try again.