# Google eclipse plugin is not working for juno 4.2

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins

Eclipse 3.8/4.2 (Juno)  Plugin for Eclipse 3.8/4.2 (Juno)   https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

using this plugin for eclipse it is showing me the error like this :

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.collections,3.2.0.v201005080500
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.oro,2.0.8.v201005080400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen,2.8.0.v20130125-0826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common.ui,2.7.0.v20130125-0826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit,2.8.0.v20130125-0826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.8.0.v20130125-0826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui,2.8.0.v20130125-0826
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem,2.0.600.v201201051400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.workbench,2.0.400.v201104251400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.core,1.2.2.v201301082148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.ui,1.2.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.utility,2.1.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core,3.2.2.v201301092252
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db,2.1.101.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.ui,2.0.1.v201208222210
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen,2.2.2.v201301082148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui,3.2.2.v201301092252
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.annotations.controller,1.1.300.v200908252030
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.annotations.core,1.1.300.v201004141630
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.frameworks,1.1.601.v201208160700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.201.v201108161900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.ui,1.4.200.v201008182133
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.ui,1.0.201.v201208292200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee,1.1.603.v201301092200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core,1.2.200.v201205030130
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb,1.1.601.v201210040812
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.annotation.model,1.1.300.v201003112036
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.jca,1.1.600.v201111012200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ui,1.1.600.v201205170400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web,1.1.601.v201212130700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jee,1.0.501.v201301091334
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.core,1.2.302.v20120503_1042
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core,3.8.3.v20130107-0100
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.screenshots,3.8.3.v20130107-0100
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui,3.8.3.v20130107-0100
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.ui,1.2.201.v201208292200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore,1.2.201.v201301092200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ui,1.0.201.v201208241600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui,1.4.300.v201111030424
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.core,1.1.602.v201210091733
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.ui,1.0.702.v201211262010
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.core,1.1.602.v201301032305
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.ui,1.0.702.v201211262010
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.internet.monitor.core,1.0.505.v20110419
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core,1.1.202.v201208171701
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.manipulation,1.0.400.v201204261600
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui,1.1.202.v201208171701
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.core,1.4.100.v20130117_1140
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery,1.0.300.v20120403_0949
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.ui,1.4.100.v20121112_1718
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.web,1.1.600.v201204190200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.web.ui,1.1.600.v201109220400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jdom,1.1.1.v201101151400
```

I ref following link but its not working for me :

[Installing JPA pluggin for Eclipse juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553706/installing-jpa-pluggin-for-eclipse-juno).

My eclipse Version: Juno 4.2.2
os is windows 2003

Answer (score 0):

When you go help > install new software. Enter the link for the plugin and down and the bottom there is a "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" check box. Uncheck that.

Comment: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.8.0.v201410302155-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.8.0.v201410302155-rel-r42)
  Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.8.0.v201410302155-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.8.0.v201410302155-rel-r42) requires 'org.eclipse.jst.server.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: So install what it's telling you your missing. I had similar problems with Juno and the help > install new software for other plugins so I upgraded to Luna

Comment: @Kirti did you find a solution for your error. I am getting the same problem.